# Ignore meta information in json

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit (on Android) with the GsonConverterFactory. The json that I get back from the endpoint has [json meta information](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-meta) in it. For example, a response would look like this:

```
{
    meta:{"some meta information"},
    data:{
        address:{
            meta:{"some other meta information"},
            data:{
                street: "Main Street",
                zip: "99999",
                state: "CA",
            },
        ...
    }
}
```

Using Gson (through the GsonConverterFactory), my data model would need to look like this (in Kotlin):

```
class Response(val data: Data1)
class Data1(val address: Address)
class Address(val Data2)
class Data2(val street: String, val zip: String, val state: String)
```

As you can see, if it's not a primitive type, objects are wrapped inside of data members. However, I don't want to include those data objects everywhere in my data model classes.

Is there an easy way, to "jump over" those data tags? I don't want to exclude them, just directly include what's inside of them. For example, the data model would look something like this:

```
class Response(val address: Address)
class Address(val street: String, val zip: String, val state: String)
```

The equivalent json would look like this:

```
{
    address:{
        street: "Main Street",
        zip: "99999",
        state: "CA",
    },
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, that's not the way the endpoint delivers the json.

Is there any way to achieve this with Gson, Jackson, or some other json parser that can run on Android?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're looking for, the best route would be writing a Gson deserializer.

Comment: I though about that as well. The problem is that in order to register a type adapter (which deserializes) I have to give it a type. But that type would change from e.g. Data to Address. So I'm afraid, that might not work (or I misunderstood your suggestion).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. My assumption is you have corresponding models that match how you want to parse the data. For example, you would have an Address adapter, which would parse that specifically how you want. Then an adapter for any other fields you want.

Comment: You are right, that would be one way. Unfortunately, my data model is nested pretty deep so I would have to write a lot of custom adapters where I really want to "get rid" of those data fields and use the value inside them directly.